# Retaining previously drawn data in a QQuickPaintedItem

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qpainter

I have a custom QML component to plot graphs derived from `QQuickPaintedItem`. In the paint method I traverse through a list of coordinates and plot them. My `paint()` is as follows

```
QRectF bounds = boundingRect();
float w = bounds.width();
float h = bounds.height();
float dx = w / listSize;

for(int i = 0; i < coordinatesList.size() - 1; ++i)
{
    QPointF m_p1(dx*i, (h/2)-(coordinatesList.at(i)*(h/4)));
    QPointF m_p2(dx*(i+1), (h/2)-(coordinatesList.at(i+1)*(h/4)));
    painter->drawLine(m_p1, m_p2);
}
```

Is there any way to retain the previously plotted points so that I don't have to repaint the entire list of points but only specific ones?

Answer (score 2):

I can't now test it but you can draw all the points on a `QPixmap`

```
m_pixmap.fill();
QPainter buffer(&m_pixmap);
....
buffer->drawLine(...);
...
```

and then paint saved pixmap on the `Canvas`.

```
painter->drawPixmap(0, 0, m_pixmap);
```

At next paint request you just paint the saved `QPixmap`. The `QPixmap` itself have to be repaint only if plot changes.

Answer (score 1):

As the first answer suggests, caching is the key, however, <s>using a `QPixmap`</s> by default this will use the raster painter backend which is not optimal, since it will involve costly ram to GPU ram transfers. Also, while the raster painter offers better quality, it is usually slower than the GL backend.

If efficiency is key, then the correct approach would be to use a `QOpenGLFramebufferObject`, draw on it with `QPainter` and `QOpenGLPaintDevice`, and in `QQuickPaintedItem::paint()` use native rendering to draw the FBO on a `QQuickItem` that uses an FBO target itself. This will give you better painting performance and avoid the overhead of ram to vram transfers.

Also, when dealing with plot components, it is a good idea to compartmentalize the drawing, for example stuff like the grid or scales should be separate components, since they don't need constant redrawing, and only draw the actual waveform and compose it on top.

Comment: A `QQuickPaintedItem` already has all the painting done using a raster engine, effectively painting on top of a texture-backed `QImage` anyway. Painting lots of short lines isn't usually any faster using the `QOpenGLPaintDevice` than using the raster backend.

Comment: The goal is not avoiding the raster painting but to avoid the ram to vram transfer.

Comment: That transfer is done using DMA and is very fast and usually doesn't involve the CPU. On modern hardware you can pretty much saturate the buses doing that transfer and the CPU won't even notice. Pushing 1024x1024 32-bit images at 60FPS is only 0.25GByte/s of bandwidth. It's nothing much unless the modern hardware is something like Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Note the "If efficiency is key" part. It is just a recommendation if optimization is needed, I don't see what is your problem with it.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Nithyesh - this approach is more efficient, but it is not as trivial as using a pixmap, I recommend testing the simple solution and only dive into the complex solution if performance is not satisfactory. Also, if your item resizes frequently, using an FBO will not be optimal, since resizing it is a costly operation on its own.